# Micronaut returns the empty body

Tags: java, aws-lambda, micronaut, graalvm, micronaut-aws

In my "Hello World" native(GraalVM) AWS Lambda application Micronaut returns the empty body instead of serializing a map as JSON. Here is the code

```java
@Controller
public class BookController {

    private static final DynamoDbClient ddb = DynamoDbClient.builder()
            .httpClient(UrlConnectionHttpClient.builder().build()).build();

    @Get("/{id}")
    public Map<String, AttributeValue> getById(@PathVariable String id) {
        GetItemResponse result = ddb.getItem(GetItemRequest.builder()
                .tableName("DemoTable")
                .key(Map.of(
                        "id", AttributeValue.builder().s(id).build()))
                .build());
        
        System.out.println(result.item());

        return result.item();
    }

}
```

The line **System.out.println(result.item())** prints all data but http response does not contain that.

Here is the response:

```json
{
  "statusCode": 200,
  "multiValueHeaders": {
    "Content-Type": [
      "application/json"
    ],
    "Date": [
      "Mon, 23 May 2022 20:26:13 GMT"
    ]
  },
  "body": "{}",
  "isBase64Encoded": false
}
```

In all examples that I have seen beans use annotation **@Introspected** for proper JSON serialization but Map definitely does not have it.

I tried to extend a HashMap class for adding the annotation, but without the result

```java
@Introspected
public class Asset extends HashMap<String, AttributeValue> {

    public Asset() {}

    public Asset(Map<String, AttributeValue> map) {
        super(map);
    }
}
```

Can someone point me to what I'm doing wrong?

> P.S. I use the next tutorial, just added DynamoDB support: https://guides.micronaut.io/latest/mn-application-aws-lambda-graalvm-gradle-java.html

Comment: This is the error. `No serializer found for class software.amazon.awssdk.services.dynamodb.model.AttributeValue and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer (to avoid exception, disable SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS)` ... AttributeValue is not serialized. This is not a problem with older version of DynamoDB client. You might have to do something like https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/issues/889#issuecomment-555339230

Comment: Alternatively, if you know the attributes they are somewhat static then you can write your own mapper class which can get serialized easily. Something like https://github.com/aws-samples/serverless-java-frameworks-samples/blob/main/micronaut/src/main/java/software/amazonaws/example/product/dao/ProductMapper.java

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to get a response body by using a [custom serializer](https://gist.github.com/nickman/991dea808b6f43e7346d6d570f3c9ffe).

```
@Controller
class HelloWorldController {
  private static final DynamoDbClient client = DynamoDbClient.builder()
    .httpClient(UrlConnectionHttpClient.builder().build()).build();

  private static final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

  static {
    SimpleModule module = new SimpleModule();
    module.addSerializer(AttributeValue.class, new AttributeValueSerializer());
    mapper.registerModule(module);
  }

  @Get("/{id}")
  public HttpResponse<String> getById(@PathVariable final String id) throws JsonProcessingException {
    GetItemResponse result = client.getItem(GetItemRequest.builder()
      .tableName("Products")
      .key(Map.of("PK", AttributeValue.builder().s(id).build()))
      .build());

    System.out.println(result.item());
    return HttpResponse.ok(mapper.writeValueAsString(result.item()));
  }
}
```